# startAt() don't have a number option for Firebase query

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

[No StartAt(numbers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRtw4.png)

Hi, according to the Query documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

There should be a startAt option for numbers. startAt ( value :  number | string | boolean | null ,  key ? :  string ) : Query

However, I could not access it in android studio. May I know did something changed or is it a bug? I can only use Double, Boolean, and String?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing Java code, but are looking at the Java**Script** documentation. These are two very different languages, even if they look superficially similar at first.

On Java the [`startAt` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#startAt(double)) indeed only takes a `Double` for a number, so if you have another type of input you'll have to convert it, for example by using `startAt(10.0)`.